# Why fread() can not store binary values in buffer after reading binary file?

Tags: binaryfiles

I expect that the following code will output the result as follows:

```
a[0] = 0
a[1] = 1
b[0] = 2
b[1] = 3
b[2] = 4
```

but the real result is:

```
a[0] = 0
a[1] = 0
b[0] = 0
b[1] = 0
b[2] = 0
```

Why? I think the original values in a[2] and b[3] will be overwrite by binary file, but the truth of the matter was quite different, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
  FILE *data;

  data = fopen ("binary.dat", "w+");

  unsigned char buffer[5];

  for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {   
      buffer[i] = i;
    }   

  fwrite (buffer, sizeof (unsigned char), 10, data);

  int a[2] = {0};
  int b[3] = {0};

  fread (a, sizeof (int), 2, data);
  fread (b, sizeof (int), 3, data);

  for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {   
      printf ("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }   

  for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {   
      printf ("b[%d] = %d\n", i, b[i]);
    }   

  fclose (data);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to read from a file that's been opened for *writing* - and you're trying to read from beyond the end of the file. If you close the file after you've written to it, then open it again for reading, I suspect you'll get different results...

Comment: solved! thank you!